# Cronjob Not Running On Root User

Tags: nginx, cron, lets-encrypt

I have the following cronjob set for my root user on my VPS. The command itself works if I run it as the root users just fine.

```
30 2 * * * service nginx stop && /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew && service nginx start > /dev/null
```

However it isn't working as I can see that my SSL certificate isn't renewing.

If I run `cat /var/log/cron` I can see the following

```
Nov 13 02:30:01 server CROND[2307]: (root) CMD (service nginx stop && /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew && service nginx start > /dev/null)
```

Which seems to indicate it ran, but clearly it hasn't done what it's supposed to.

Other cronjobs on my normal user seem to work fine, however I can't use that user for the crons as I need to temporarily stop Nginx for this cron.

Any ideas on how I can further debug this and sort it out?

*** Edit: ***

I tried running it to log and the following error was shown in the log `/bin/sh: service: command not found`

Comment: Direct output to a log file instead of /dev/null. What do you get?

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown see my edit.

Comment: You probably need to enclose the command list in parentheses to redirect their combined output to a logfile.

Comment: @RichardSmith that worked and I got the following error in the log: `/bin/sh: service: command not found` How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `service` command was not in the crons PATH so I had to use the full path which is `/sbin/service`.

That meant my final cron command was

```
30 2 * * * (/sbin/service nginx stop && /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew && /sbin/service nginx start) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Which is now working.

It looks like as a general rule, specifying the full path to any shell commands is best practice.